# Setting up a local SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to set up a local svn to version control a really big project.
Normally i have only used premade SVNs for school stuff, is it even possible to create a 
local svn folder that will keep track of changes.

I am using `svnadmin create myrepo` to create the repository, and then `svn import home/dev/svntest file:///home/dev/myrepo` to import the file there. However when I run that command a file called `svn-commit.tmp` is created with the following text in it:

```
"--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

A    hello.txt:///~myrepo/test1"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a commit message for your `svn import`. Add `-m "Initial import of project svntest"` to your `svn import` line.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up to @Mike

1. Don't worry about this strange file, just test results of import
2. Conventional layout of repo tree (/trunk+ /tags +/branches) from the beginning may have some benefits (i.e before import perform 3 mkdir and import into `file:///home/dev/myrepo/trunk`)
3. You can always see at the repo and control results tree using `svn ls -v -R file:///home/dev/myrepo` command